# Unable to unbind a function using tkinter

Tags: python, binding, tkinter, python-3.5

I am working with Tkinter in Python 3.5 and I encounter a weird problem.

I used the [tkinterbook about events and bindings](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm) to write this simple example:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

frame = Frame(root, width=100, height=100)

def callback(event):
    print("clicked at", event.x, event.y)
    # frame.unbind("<Button-1>", callback)

frame.bind("<Button-1>", callback)
frame.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

It works fine, but if I try to unbind the callback (just uncomment the line), it fails with the following error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Delgan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1549, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Delgan\Desktop\Test\test.py", line 9, in callback
    frame.unbind("<Button-1>", callback)
  File "C:\Users\Delgan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1105, in unbind
    self.deletecommand(funcid)
  File "C:\Users\Delgan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 441, in deletecommand
    self.tk.deletecommand(name)
TypeError: deletecommand() argument must be str, not function
```

This is not clear, I am not sure if it is a bug in tkinter or if I am doing something wrong.

`frame.unbind("<Button-1>")` works fine but I would like to remove this exact callback instead of a global remove.

Comment: I can not reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The second argument to `unbind` is a 'funcid', not a function.  `help(root.unbind)` returns

> `unbind(sequence, funcid=None)` method of tkinter.Tk instance. 
>   Unbind for this widget for event SEQUENCE  the function identified with FUNCID.

Many tk functions return tk object ids that can be arguments for other funtions, and bind is one of them.

```
>>> i = root.bind('<Button-1>', int)
>>> i
'1733092354312int'
>>> root.unbind('<Button-1>', i)  # Specific binding removed.
```

Buried in the output from `help(root.bind)` is this: "Bind will return an identifier to allow deletion of the bound function with unbind without memory leak."

Comment: Oh, that makes sense, thank you, I did not think to this. Maybe the API changed with a recent version of Python, which could explain why examples I found was using the function itself and not the funcid, and why @BillalBEGUERADJ does not have the same issue.

Comment: I know this comes late but for all future people having this problem: If you just wish to unbind this one function do: ´´´root.unbind("",<id>)´´´ because the above example will remove ALL bindings with the given sequence (´´´'<Button-1>'´´´) no mather the functions id.

Comment: Some people think one can unbind a specific handler out of multiple handlers bound on a widget(not the root), by calling ```unbind()``` on the root instead of the widget. (See the comments on [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76026886/1186624) on another question.) What about mentioning this is incorrect?

Comment: @Nummer_420, that will cause an undefined behavior. See [the implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.11.3/Lib/tkinter/__init__.py#L1450) for a detail.