# Python : How replace double click in Treeview

Tags: python, click, double, unbind

I have a problem to replace the double click. I have a treeview and when I click it open a node. I want to replace by another function but he keep the open/close node.

I have do many test but without success. So my question is how to replace a binding widget ?

I play with this line for test but I think need another function for work. If I unbind and after create a new bind that doesn't work :o(

```
self.unbind('<Double-1>')
self.tree.bind('<Double-1>', lambda e: 'break')
#self.tree.bind('<Double-1>', self.test)

def test(self):
    pass

#tmp.tree.bind("<Double-1>", self.onDoubleClick_datagrid, add="+")
tmp.tree.bind("<Double-1>", self.onDoubleClick_datagrid)
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to unbind a function using tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37902503/unable-to-unbind-a-function-using-tkinter)

Comment: Thank you. With your link >I find the solution. If another person search it... It's simple, it enough too put : return "break" at the end of new function bind.